# How can I open sublime text 3 without restoring or saving projects as a one-time request?

Tags: sublimetext3, projects

My normal workflow is to have Sublime Test 3 re-open the last opened project files; this works great for me, normally. But when I'm not at work, my laptop does not have access to the NFS shares, and when the projects get opened, all of the opened files disappear; this happens most often when I just need to jot down a quick note or something.

Is there a way, without editing user pref files, to open up the editor without loading the current projects as a one-off occurrence? Command-line solutions are fine, and may even be preferable.

Comment: this has also been asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685595/start-empty-session-in-sublimetext but unfortunately it has no answers. You say without editing the preferences, so I guess temporarily renaming the `Session.sublime-session` file is out? https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html

Comment: There'a no command line option to do that and I don't think a plugin would help either because that's outside of what the plugin API can do. I would imagine that @KeithHall has the best option; you could say create a shell script with an extra option that moves away the session file and then puts it back (it would have to specify `-w` to make sublime wait for everything to close).